# Understanding dynamic expansion of struct

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to understand how structs work.

In the following code output, I see the values are getting correctly assigned even before calloc and realloc.

Can someone explain how this is and how do i error check if my struct is being properly created.

Thanks a lot for your time and help!!

```
typedef struct db
{
    int x;
};
int main()
{
    int n = 1, i;
    char yn = 'y';
    db *tmp_row, *row;
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        printf("tmp_row address, size,value - %u, %d, %d\n", &tmp_row + n,
               sizeof(tmp_row), tmp_row + n);
    tmp_row = (db *)calloc(1, sizeof(db));
    printf("\n\n");
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        printf("tmp_row address, size,value - %u, %d, %d\n", &tmp_row + n,
               sizeof(tmp_row), tmp_row + n);
    tmp_row = (db *)realloc(tmp_row, n * sizeof(db));
    printf("\n\n");
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        printf("tmp_row address, size,value - %u, %d, %d\n", &tmp_row + n,
               sizeof(tmp_row), tmp_row + n);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the values are getting correctly assigned"? Could you clarify what output you're seeing, and what you're expecting to see?

Comment: assuming that you didn't put the right inclusions in the code for brevity, your `typedef` still lacks of a name for the alias to that struct.

Comment: Hi, The address and values are going up by the expected amounts. the address is going up by 8bytes(my os is 64bit) and the value, which i believe is the address of int x is going up by 4.

Comment: You are using the uninitialized variable `tmp_row` in the first `printf()`, at that time, `tmp_row` has a undetermined value.

Comment: @user2485710, could you please explain what is missing. I'm still learning the basics.

Comment: It should be `typedef struct db {int x;}T;` , with this you can use the struct as a type with a declaration such as `T t;` in your `main`.

Comment: @leeduhem, that's what i was expecting too, garbage values, but the output looks correct (to me)

Comment: @user2485710, can i write typedef struct {int x;}db; ?

Comment: @csaw What do you mean "correct"? What is the wrong output you expected?

Comment: @csaw yep +randomchars

Comment: @leeduhem, in 1st printf i was expecting 1 value where and address is assigned to 'tmp_row' and then the prg to crash. 2nd 'printf' to be 2 correct values and then crash. so on...

Comment: @csaw You cannot predict the output of this code, but there will be no crash, because you do not access invalid memory address. `tmp_row` itself is a variable, it has its own address. `tmp_row+n` will compute a new address, but will not derefer this address.

Comment: @leeduhem, how do i error check/make sure, that a block was reserved correctly each time?

Comment: @csaw As far as I know, there is no way to do such check.

Comment: @leeduhem, i added `tmp_row=tmp_row+40;tmp_row->x=2;` to my code and the value of `tmp_row->x=2;` was assigned correctly. so, further down, if another variable or prg uses that same mem location will my value for `int x `get over written? if so how do i "reserve" that memory space

Comment: @csaw : To **reserve** the memory space you use `'alloc` family of functions.

Comment: @csaw In your case, `tmp_row=tmp_row+40;tmp_row->x=2;` is undefined behavior. It may or may not crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do i error check if my struct is being properly created.

Check whether `malloc/calloc/realloc` returned `NULL`. In this latter case the call failed and no memory had been allocated.

```
tmp_row = calloc(1, sizeof(db));
if (NULL == tmp_row)
{
  perror("calloc() failed");
  return -1;
}

...
```

---

Also use the conversion specifier `"p"` to print values of `void`-pointers and `"zu"` for `size_t`:

```
printf("tmp_row address, size, value - %p, %zu, %p\n", 
  (void*) (&tmp_row + n),
  sizeof(tmp_row), 
  (void*) (tmp_row + n)
);
```

Comment: thanks everybody, i actually have a better understanding now. @alk, %zu, is returning zu... didn't know about %p, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't have any error.

In this statement:

```
printf("tmp_row address, size,value - %u, %d, %d\n", &tmp_row + n,
           sizeof(tmp_row), tmp_row + n);
```

you are accessing the address of `tmp_row` and the value of `tmp_row`, since `tmp_row` is not initialized it will be storing some random value. Note that it would have been invalid memory access if you would have tried to print `*(tmp_row + n);` ,i.e. the value at some random address.

Accessing a garbage value is neither an error nor undefined behavior.

This is same as you define `int a;` and then try to access the address of `a`, or print the value of `a`, or print the value of `a + 10`. This is all valid, however you will not get any deterministic output.

Also, your code does not have any undefined behavior because you are not accessing the values of those memory locations, you are just printing those addresses.

And hence it is obvious that if `tmp_row` is a pointer then the value of `tmp_row + 1` will be `4` greater than the value of `tmp_row` (for 32-bit system).

As you mentioned in comments, you were hoping for a crash. For that, you can try accessing values at these memory addresses and then probably it will crash. Best of luck with that!! :-)

Comment: what is the correct way to dynamically allocate struct?

Comment: If you know the amount of memory you require, then use either `malloc` or `calloc` otherwise allocate some memory using `malloc` and then use `realloc` to extend/shorten memory buffer.